# How to clear DOM elements created with jQuery from memory?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

My app is using jQuery to add lots of DOM elements on the fly. All these elements are put into a main container div.

Then, every time a new page is shown, this container div is removed using jQuery's remove();
The problem is, it seems that all the children of this container div still seem to be listed under "Nodes" in Chrome's devtools timeline.

The longer I run my app, the more DOM elements I'm creating! But when looking at the HTML source, the nodes aren't there.

[image: Detached elements]

My code:

```
    // creating lots of jquery elements and appending them to maincontainer
    var elm = document.createElement("DIV");
    var jq = jQuery(elm).text("hello");
    maincontainer.append(jq);

    // then, the main container(also a jquery object) is removed using
    maincontainer.remove();
```

What is wrong with clearing DOM nodes from memory this way? Why are they retained under "nodes"?

Comment: Just wondering, have you try without using jQuery but only JS, same result?

Comment: Can we see a little bit more of the code that surrounds that code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After removing the elements from page, just clear the variables also.. so the elements which are stored internally also gets cleaned.. If the element is stored in `divElements` variable,

```
divElements.remove();
divElements = null;
```

I don't know it may a solution for you... but it works in my application..

Comment: You were correct. I had to call remove(); on each of the main containers children. Apparently the jQuery data keeps existing if you don't call remove() - even when the DOM element is removed from the HTML page!

Answer (score 2):

I would pressume, it is still stored under nodes because you've reserved that element in a variable, forever making it accessible.

So it will reserve...

```
var elm = document.createElement("div");
```

Because that variable may be accessed again to do anything you wish to do with it, like add it back into the page and so forth.

Edit: Also if you want to 'clear' variables from stack, or in your terms 'memory' you might want to consider creating the variable under a local scope...
e.g.

```
<button type="button" id="btn-example">Click me!</button>

$(document).on("click", "#btn-example", function() {
  var elm = $('div');
  elm.remove();
});
```

or in raw JS...

```
<button type="button" onclick="removeDiv();">Click me!</button>

function removeDiv() {
  var elm = document.getElementByTagName('div');
  elm.parentNode.removeChild(elm);
}
```

This is because local variables are created when the function is activated, then destroyed when the function ceases.

Comment: The problem was that I did not call remove(); on each child specifically. I just removed the HTML elements from the DOM - but apparenty that keeps them in memory if they were created with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Always use:

`$("ElementName").detach()`

When you want to remove an element from DOM, it will not increase Memory of DOM and browser will not be stuck.